# Why is `item["error"]: "message"` NOT a syntax error in python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I found a bug in my code tonight where I had written:

```
item["error"]: "message"
```

instead of:

```
item["error"] = "message"
```

What I can't figure out is why the original line did not cause a syntax error.  What is going on there?  This is not inside a dict declaration; this is just a regular standalone line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've accidentally [annotated](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-526-syntax-for-variable-annotations) `item["error"]` with the value `"message"`.  (What that actually means is up to whatever code processes the annotations, which by default is nothing.)  Variable annotations are a new feature in Python 3.6.

Comment: I was unaware of PEP526 and I think it is a terrible decision to use such similar syntax.

Comment: I tried `pylint` on such line of code. Hoped to get some kind of `pointless-statement` warning, but no, `pylint` does not see any problem. Well, it isn't pointless statement indeed, because it creates new annotation. But without errors and without warnings it is a "gotcha".

Comment: I 've now thought about this a bit and think it would have made far more sense to use `@` as the annotation operator. `item["error"]  @ "message`.  This would be similar to `@property`  and java annotations.  It is also visually a great distance from `=` which `:` is not.  Especially given that `:` assumes the role of `=` within the construction of a `dict`.